# While fast scrolling collectionview the first row data duplicate in the last row

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

i wanted to make an application with a design that looks like the app store so i followed let's build that app tutorial on how to build it and the result was excellent, when i tested it on my device it seem that when i fast scroll the collection-view the data that's in the first row take place on the last row and when scroll fast up again, the data that supposed to be in the last row i found it in the first row and when i scroll left and right in the row when the cell go off the screen it re-update to the right data but when fast scroll up and down fast again the data between the first row and last row go crazy.
i added image to the case in the end of the code.i spent 5 days trying to fix this but no luck at all i tried alot of solution like reset the data in the cell to nil before reseting it and alot other u will find it in the code  but no luck , I really appreciate any help you can provide, Thanks

***update**
 after @Joe Daniels answer all the data are staple and work fine except the images it still go crazy when fast scrolling but it return   after 7/8 sec of stopping scrolling to the right image

**first class that contain the vertical collectionview**
i made the width of the cell equal the width of the view , i tried the cell.tag == index-path.row solution but it didn't work

```
        class HomePageVC: UIViewController  ,  UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout ,SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     mainProductsRow.delegate = self
    mainProductsRow.dataSource = self
}


   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            if let count = productCategory?.count {
            return count + 1
        }
        return 0

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let   cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: LargeHomeCategoriesCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! LargeHomeCategoriesCell
        cell.categoriesHomePageVC = self
        cell.catIndexPath = indexPath.row
        cell.productCategories = productCategory
        cell.seeMore.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.seeMoreCat(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
        let   cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RowCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeCategoriesCell

        cell.categoriesHomePageVC = self
        cell.catIndexPath = indexPath.row
    cell.seeMore.tag = (indexPath.row - 1 )
    cell.seeMore.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.seeMore(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
 //   cell.tag = indexPath.row - 1
    cell.productCategory = nil
    //if cell.tag == indexPath.row - 1{
        cell.productCategory = productCategory?[indexPath.row - 1 ]

 //   }
        return cell


}
```

**Second Class that contain the horizontal collectionview that is in the first collectionview cell **
in the cell-for-item-At-index-Path i printed the index-path.row when the view-load it printed 0 , 1 ,2 and didn't print the last index '3' and the same thing happen again when i scroll to the end of the collection view

```
class HomeCategoriesCell: UICollectionViewCell , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout , UICollectionViewDelegate{




@IBOutlet weak var seeMore: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var categorytitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productsCollectionView: UICollectionView!

let favFuncsClass = FavItemsFunctionality()
let onCartFuncsClass = OnCartFunctionality()

var productCategory : ProductCategories? {
    didSet {
        if let categoryTitle = productCategory?.name {
            categorytitle.text = categoryTitle
        }
    }

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    recivedNotification()

    productsCollectionView.delegate = self
    productsCollectionView.dataSource = self
    productsCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = productCategory?.products?.count {
        return count
    }
    return 0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print(indexPath.row)
    let   cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HProductCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeProductCell
    cell.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.productImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlaceHolder")
    cell.productTitle.text = nil
    cell.productPrice.text = nil
    cell.discountLabel.text = nil
    cell.preDiscountedPrice.text = nil
    cell.favButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"Heart_icon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    cell.addToCart.setImage(UIImage(named:"cart"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    cell.configCell(products: nil)
    if cell.tag == indexPath.row {
        cell.configCell(products: productCategory?.products?[indexPath.item])
    }
    cell.catNum = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
    // Thanks to Joe Daniels i added this code and my nightmare become way less scary :P 
      override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    productsCollectionView.reloadData()
  }

}
```

**Product Cell**
 i tried the prepare-For-Reuse() and reseted all the data to nil but still didn't work

```
  class HomeProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {

func configCell(products :productDetails?){
      if let title = products?.name {
        self.productTitle.text = title
    }else {  self.productTitle.text = nil}

    if let price = products?.price {
        self.productPrice.text = "\(price)"
    }else { self.productPrice.text = nil }

    }

  override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.productImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "PlaceHolder")
    productTitle.text = nil
    productPrice.text = nil
    discountLabel.text = nil
    preDiscountedPrice.text = nil
    favButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"Heart_icon"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    addToCart.setImage(UIImage(named:"cart"), for: UIControlState.normal)

}
```

**i took a screen shoots of the case you can find it    [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzmfQ.jpg)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Found the Perfect Solution that worked for me as magic after 15 days of suffering xD i used this library (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

To use it in swift put this line in your bridging Header

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

And in the collectionViewCell i used this line

```
self.productImage.sd_setImage(with: myUrl , placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"yourPlaceHolderImage")
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner collectionView has no way of knowing that it went off screen. do a `reload` in prepareForReuse

Comment: i tried it and it worked on the string data like magic but the images when fast scrolling it miss up and dublicate and show in the wrong cell but it change to the right image after around 8 / 9 sec but with out doubt u saved me Thank you very much ^-^ . do u have any idea how to prevent the images from doing this glitch ?